# "Дождь" и "ждать", "дождаться" - однокоренные ли слова?

Tags: этимология

И еще один вопрос на ту же тему. "Дождь" и "ждать", "дождаться" - родственные слова или просто созвучные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не родственны и даже не очень созвучны. Корни совершенно разные.
Дождъ - от "дъжджь", то же; ждать - от "жьдати", хотеть, страстно желать.